# Creating a mirrored word based on symmetry of letter

Tags: python, string, list-comparison

I created this program that supposed to display the mirror image of a word if it is symmetrical. Unfortunately, when I test "TIMOTHY" it shows it cannot be mirrored and I can not figure out why this does not work.

```
#Program for creating a mirrored
#image word#
def main():

    mirrors = ["A","H","I","M","O","T","U","V","W","X","Y"
               "b","d","i","l","m","o","p","t","v","w","x"]

    word = input("Enter in the word you'd like mirrored: ")

    for x in word:
        if x not in mirrors:
            y = True
            break

    if y == True:
        print("Sorry your word can not be mirrored")


    wordlist = ''.join(word[i] for i in range(len(word) -1, -1, -1 ))

    print(wordlist)




main()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mirrors = ["A","H","I","M","O","T","U","V","W","X","Y"
               "b","d","i","l","m","o","p","t","v","w","x"]
```

Here's the problem. "b" follows "Y" without any intervening comma. A little-known quirk of Python is that two adjacent string literals will be automatically concatenated. So neither "Y" nor "b" are in your list, but "Yb" is.

To fix this, add a comma.

```
mirrors = ["A","H","I","M","O","T","U","V","W","X","Y",
               "b","d","i","l","m","o","p","t","v","w","x"]
```

Also, you should do `y = False` before your loop if you don't want to get an `UnboundLocalError` later during the `if y == True` block.